# Javascript function return value into PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following code which outputs a select menu...

```
echo "<select name='household' id='house' onchange='updateHousehold()'>";
    while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
        $housename = $row['name'];
        echo "<option value='$housename'>";
            echo $housename;
        echo "</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
```

...and the following javascript function:

```
function updateHousehold() {
    var housename = document.getElementById("house").value;
    return housename;
}
```

I'm trying to have the select menu such that the value of it is always stored in a PHP variable. So it would be in a php variable upon the loading of the page, but if the user changes the value it should update accordingly.

I know I need to use AJAX to do this, however I don't understand how to use it at all - all the answers on stackexchange I either didn't understand or didn't work (probably because I did it wrong).

How can I store the function's return value in a variable, explained in very simple terms and good code examples?

*Extra: I'm going to be using this variable to query a sql query, so this query would need to be called every time the value of the select changes. I can do this via a PHP function, however is there any way I can call the PHP function after the value of the select input changes?*

Comment: The javascript variable only exists in the *browser* that the user is using (Chrome / Firefox / IE or other browser). The php code is on the *server* and knows nothing about the javascript variables. You can send the javascript variable in several ways to the server. If the page is a form that is posted back you can assign the value to a hidden field (google hidden field postback php) usually these forms have a form element with an action attribute specified and a button that performs the post. You can also send the value with ajax, but how to do that depends on the rest of your code

Comment: The select input is already a part of the form on the page, so I'd like to use AJAX - however I have no idea how to do so.

Comment: This sample https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp seems be similar with what you want to do